# What is the best way to uninstall Ububtu 13.04 from a PC dual booting 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a partition, dual booting with Ubuntu 12.04. Now I would like to remove the partition and Ubuntu 13.04 without having to lose Ubuntu 12.04 or reformatting the entire hard drive.

How can I do this?

Comment: its 13.04 run on dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Which "partition" are you wanting to remove?  12.04, or the other OS?

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu 12.04, Install gparted, running it, identifies Ubuntu 13.04 partition is installed, right click and delete partition.
Make sure your boot partition is Ubuntu 12.04 or MBR, before restart.

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual machine, and have the VM reside on either the Ubuntu side, or the other OS side.

VirtualBox is an easy-to-use VM system, but if you plan on running 13.04 all the time, you're better off not using a VM.